# PHP problem in functions with params

Tags: php, html

I ma not quit experienced on PHP programming, and I am making an application PHO + HTML.
I am in the point that I am getting a list of results from the database and I want to provide the user a method to edit or delete each of them.

My code is:

```
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($res)){
            $_SESSION['nombre'] = $row["nombre"]; 
            $nombre = $row["nombre"];
            $descripcion = $row["descripcion"];
            $imgPath = $row["imagen"];
            $id = $row["id"];
            echo $id;
            ?>
            <!-- Each element on the table -->
            <table width="400" border="0" align="right">
                  <tr>
                    <td><p><?php echo $nombre; ?>
                </p>
                    <p class="TextoNormal"> <?php echo $descripcion; ?></p></td>
                        <!-- html code -->
                    <td align="center"><input name="guest" type="button" value="<?php echo $nombre; ?>" onclick="window.open('servoclientapplet.html?serverIP=ip','newwin')" /></td>
                    <td align="center"><input name="guest" type="button" value="Editar" onclick="<?php EditApp($id); ?>" /></td>
                    <td align="center"><input name="guest" type="button" value="Eliminar" onclick="<?php echo($id); elminar($id); ?>" /></td>
                  </tr>

            <?php
        }
```

But neither `EditApp($id)` nor `elminar($id)` are receiver their parameters. How could I send it to them? In addition, to `EditApp` I would like to open a modal panel or a new page, to allow the user to write the updates, and then execute the query.
I add also each function code:

**EditApp**

```
function EditApp($id) { 
...
}
```

**Delete**

```
function elminar($id){
...
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does `EditApp` and `elminar` function does? I hope they print some javascript... I think you should read some tutorial before starting to actually program.

Comment: Edit and delete some tables on my database. I know how to do this in javascript, but the question is how could be done using php, if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Onclick is for javascript, not php.  Instead, just create a form and have buttons for edit and delete.  Pass id with POST.

Comment: Ok, if there is no way using php, I will use javascript, but I'd like to use php instead

Comment: You *can* use php.  Use a form.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you mean. Thanks

Comment: Ups, I didn't write the whole comment, sorry. I understand, but I was looking for a different way, because I don't have input where the user will write something, the data is already there in different variables, like $id, $nombre. How could I send this data to the functions?

Comment: Instead of prompting for them, make them type hidden: <input type="hidden" name="Language" value="English">